# loop through database and show in table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to loop though my users database to show each username in the table in their own row. I can only get it to show one user but loops through this the number of rows there are. Code is below

```
<?php
require_once ('../login/connection.php');
include ('functions.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results=mysql_query($query);
$row_count=mysql_num_rows($results);
$row_users = mysql_fetch_array($results);

echo "<table>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++)
    {
    echo "<table><tr><td>".($row_users['email'])."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) fetches a single row - you typically use it in a while loop to eat all the rows in the result set, e.g.

```
echo "<table>";

while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    //output a row here
    echo "<tr><td>".($row_users['email'])."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Outdated answer, make sure to use MySQLi instead of MySQL http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 4):

You're only fetching one row:

```
$row_users = mysql_fetch_array($results);
```

You're never calling a fetch again so you're not really looping through anything.

I'd suggest changing your loop to the following:

```
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['email'])."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The while loop will loop through the results and assign a row to $row, until you run out of rows.  Plus no need to deal with getting the count of results at that point.  This is the "usual" way to loop through results from a DB in php.

Answer (score 4):

In the new MYSQLI, I use this coding

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row_count=mysqli_num_rows($results);

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<tr><td>".($row['id'])."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_query($con,$query); 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>".($row_users['email'])."</td></tr>";
```

You're echoing out a `<table>` tag again. Remove that so your code looks like this:

```
echo "<table>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$row_count; $i++)
    {
    echo "<tr><td>".($row_users['email'])."</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to output a table within a table the way you're doing it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `users`");
$num_emails = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<table><caption>There are/is $num_emails email(s)</caption>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['email']}</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Something like that should work.