# Fetching districts of a state using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a Pin Code search directory. I want to display districts count and district names of selected state as given in the following example. If there are 4 districts in Delhi state, the data should be rendered as:

```
<p>There are 4 districts in Delhi</p>
<ul>
<li>District 1</li>
<li>District 2</li>
<li>District 3</li>
<li>District 4</li>
</ul>
```

Please note that there are various rows of each district but I would like to use rowcount here to count all the rows of each district as 1, e.g. if there are 50 rows containing all 4 different districts, the total number should be 4.

The URL of this page is something like `domain.com/pincode/state.php?state=StateName`

Here is my code:

```
<?php   
$state = $_GET['state'];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbuser','pass','dbname');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}    
$sql = "SELECT stateName, districtName FROM pincodes WHERE stateName='$state'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);           
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                                              
        echo "" . $row["districtName"]. "";
        echo " | | ";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>No results Found</p>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<h1><?php echo $state; ?> Pincode</h1>
<p>There are a total of <?php echo $rowcount; ?> districts in <?php echo $state; ?>.</p>
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Vikas

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: for example, if there are total of 8 districts in a state, I want to render districts of a state in the following way:

State Name (as heading)
There are a total of 8 districts in "State"
district 1
district 2
district 3
district 4
district 5
district 6
district 7
district 8

Comment: Make a loop on the result from the DB and render the data in an html table. Do you need the actual code?

Comment: actually I'm not that good in php coding. Could you provide me the code? All I'm coding this website using Google's help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop through database and show in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848905/loop-through-database-and-show-in-table)

Comment: @zionbenyacov could you pls provide me the actual code???

Answer (score 0):

You may use following query:

```
SELECT `stateName`,count(`districtName`) as totcount 
FROM `pincodes` WHERE `statename`='$state'
group by `statename`
```

Comment: It's still not working. As a total of row count, I'm getting only 1 district while there are around 9 district of the selected state. Also, district names are not rendering on the page.

Comment: Made some changes to make it working as `$sql="SELECT `stateName`, `districtName`, count(`districtName`) as totcount FROM `pincodes` WHERE `stateName`='$state' group by `districtName`";` It's working like a charm now !! :)