# PHP - How to set the 'for' loop test counter to run depending on the number of entries

Tags: php

I'm currently updating the database with selected values, however, I am using a for loop to process for each entry. But I can only do this to a select number, currently 6 as shown below.

```
 for ($ind = 0; $ind <6; $ind++ )
```

How would I make it loop through all & then stop?

I'm currently getting the values from another page using $_POST & then submitting them to the database on this page. As shown below:

```
for ($ind = 0; $ind <6; $ind++ ) {
        $SID = $_POST['SID' . $ind];

        $week1 = $_POST ['week1' . $ind];
        $week2 = $_POST ['week2' . $ind];
        $week3 = $_POST ['week3' . $ind];
        $week4 = $_POST ['week4' . $ind];
        $week5 = $_POST ['week5' . $ind];
        $week6 = $_POST ['week6' . $ind];
        $week7 = $_POST ['week7' . $ind];
        $week8 = $_POST ['week8' . $ind];
        $week9 = $_POST ['week9' . $ind];
        $week10 = $_POST ['week10' . $ind];


        $sqlQuery = "Update weekbyweek SET  Week_1=".$week1.", Week_2=".$week2.", Week_3=".$week3.",  Week_4=".$week4.", Week_5=".$week5.", Week_6=".$week6.", Week_7=".$week7.", Week_8=".$week8.", Week_9=".$week9.", Week_10=".$week10." WHERE SID='".$SID."'";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);


        $statement->execute(['$Week_1' => $week1, '$Week_2' => $week2,'$Week_3' => $week3, '$Week_4' => $week4,'$Week_5' => $week5, '$Week_6' => $week6,'$Week_7' => $week7, '$Week_8' => $week8,'$Week_9' => $week9, '$Week_10' => $week10]);

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [loop through database and show in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848905/loop-through-database-and-show-in-table)

Comment: A (possible) alternative is to use `foreach()` instead.

Comment: I'm struggling to use the foreach loop (as I've never used one before) how would I set it as an array & loop it. I've updated the question to show more information.

Comment: what is `$week1 = $_POST ['week1' . $ind];` ? Can you share your html codes (especially inputs) or screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**foreach**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop instead of **for**. The foreach loop is mainly used for looping through the values of an array.

```
<?php
foreach (array as $value) { 
    // Code to be executed;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend this instead "for" because of perfomance. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, how would I set the array and run the foreach loop, I've updated my code, to hopefully explain my problem a little more.

Comment: @Marker thanks. The time difference is going to be minimal in most cases. If you are not working with very large data in your project, you will not feel any difference with **foreach**.

Comment: of course, but if it does not require additional work, then why not? :)

Comment: Of course :) The question has been edited and extra codes added. I think the **for()** will be more appropriate now. I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a count that will check the length of your data array.
Below will loop 8 times and then stop.

In below case the data is an array. If working with databaseso you would have to query the database for the X amount setting that you would need, stored the result in a variable and set the count to that variable value.

```
$data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for ($i=0; $i <= count($data) ; $i++) {
  // code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
if( !empty( $items ) ){
    for ( $i=0; $i < count( $items ) ; $i++ ) {
      //code here
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach( $items as $item ){
//code here
}
```